# ASP.NET MVC 5 Showing 10 rows out of 500 records in Jquery Datatables With Server Side Processing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I Have a problem with my Jquery datatables. It shows only the first 10 rows out of 500 records in my database. Can someone help me to solve this problem.

**Here is my code :**

CONTROLLER :

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using WinWin.Models;

namespace WinWin.Controllers
{
    public class PostController : Controller
    {  
        [Route("post")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Route("post/ajaxpost")]
        public JsonResult ajaxpost(DTParameters param)
        {
            try
            {
                using (WintayoEntities db = new WintayoEntities())
                {
                    var source = new List<Post>();

                    foreach (var p in db.ccp_post.ToList())
                    {
                        source.Add(new Post
                        {
                            id = p.post_id,
                            title = p.title,
                            date = p.post_on.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                            views = p.pageviews,
                            published = (p.is_published == 0) ? "Draft" : "Published",
                            featured = (p.is_featured == 0) ? "No" : "Yes",
                            action = string.Format(@"<a href=""#""><i class=""fa fa-edit""></i></a>&nbsp;<a href=""#""><i class=""fa fa-trash-o""></i></a>")

                        });
                    }

                    List<String> columnSearch = new List<String>();

                    foreach (var col in param.Columns)
                    {
                        columnSearch.Add(col.Search.Value);
                    }

                    List<Post> data = new ResultPost().GetResult(param.Search.Value, param.SortOrder, param.Start, param.Length, source, columnSearch);

                    int count = new ResultPost().Count(param.Search.Value, data, columnSearch);

                    DTResult<Post> result = new DTResult<Post>
                    {
                        draw = param.Draw,
                        data = data,
                        recordsFiltered = count,
                        recordsTotal = count
                    };

                    return Json(result);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Json(new { error = e.Message });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DATATABLE VIEW MODEL**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WinWin.Models
{   
    /// <summary>
    /// A full result, as understood by jQuery DataTables.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The data type of each row.</typeparam>
    public class DTResult<T>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The draw counter that this object is a response to - from the draw parameter sent as part of the data request.
        /// Note that it is strongly recommended for security reasons that you cast this parameter to an integer, rather than simply echoing back to the client what it sent in the draw parameter, in order to prevent Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.
        /// </summary>
        public int draw { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Total records, before filtering (i.e. the total number of records in the database)
        /// </summary>
        public int recordsTotal { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Total records, after filtering (i.e. the total number of records after filtering has been applied - not just the number of records being returned for this page of data).
        /// </summary>
        public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The data to be displayed in the table.
        /// This is an array of data source objects, one for each row, which will be used by DataTables.
        /// Note that this parameter's name can be changed using the ajaxDT option's dataSrc property.
        /// </summary>
        public List<T> data { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The additional columns that you can send to jQuery DataTables for automatic processing.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class DTRow
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Set the ID property of the dt-tag tr node to this value
        /// </summary>
        public virtual string DT_RowId
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add this class to the dt-tag tr node
        /// </summary>
        public virtual string DT_RowClass
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add this data property to the row's dt-tag tr node allowing abstract data to be added to the node, using the HTML5 data-* attributes.
        /// This uses the jQuery data() method to set the data, which can also then be used for later retrieval (for example on a click event).
        /// </summary>
        public virtual object DT_RowData
        {
            get { return null; }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The parameters sent by jQuery DataTables in AJAX queries.
    /// </summary>
    public class DTParameters
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Draw counter.
        /// This is used by DataTables to ensure that the Ajax returns from server-side processing requests are drawn in sequence by DataTables (Ajax requests are asynchronous and thus can return out of sequence).
        /// This is used as part of the draw return parameter (see below).
        /// </summary>
        public int Draw { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// An array defining all columns in the table.
        /// </summary>
        public DTColumn[] Columns { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// An array defining how many columns are being ordering upon - i.e. if the array length is 1, then a single column sort is being performed, otherwise a multi-column sort is being performed.
        /// </summary>
        public DTOrder[] Order { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Paging first record indicator.
        /// This is the start point in the current data set (0 index based - i.e. 0 is the first record).
        /// </summary>
        public int Start { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Number of records that the table can display in the current draw.
        /// It is expected that the number of records returned will be equal to this number, unless the server has fewer records to return.
        /// Note that this can be -1 to indicate that all records should be returned (although that negates any benefits of server-side processing!)
        /// </summary>
        public int Length { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Global search value. To be applied to all columns which have searchable as true.
        /// </summary>
        public DTSearch Search { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Custom column that is used to further sort on the first Order column.
        /// </summary>
        public string SortOrder
        {
            get
            {
                return Columns != null && Order != null && Order.Length > 0
                    ? (Columns[Order[0].Column].Data + (Order[0].Dir == DTOrderDir.DESC ? " " + Order[0].Dir : string.Empty))
                    : null;
            }
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A jQuery DataTables column.
    /// </summary>
    public class DTColumn
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Column's data source, as defined by columns.data.
        /// </summary>
        public string Data { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Column's name, as defined by columns.name.
        /// </summary>
        public string Name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Flag to indicate if this column is searchable (true) or not (false). This is controlled by columns.searchable.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Searchable { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Flag to indicate if this column is orderable (true) or not (false). This is controlled by columns.orderable.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Orderable { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Specific search value.
        /// </summary>
        public DTSearch Search { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// An order, as sent by jQuery DataTables when doing AJAX queries.
    /// </summary>
    public class DTOrder
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Column to which ordering should be applied.
        /// This is an index reference to the columns array of information that is also submitted to the server.
        /// </summary>
        public int Column { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ordering direction for this column.
        /// It will be dt-string asc or dt-string desc to indicate ascending ordering or descending ordering, respectively.
        /// </summary>
        public DTOrderDir Dir { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sort orders of jQuery DataTables.
    /// </summary>
    public enum DTOrderDir
    {
        ASC,
        DESC
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A search, as sent by jQuery DataTables when doing AJAX queries.
    /// </summary>
    public class DTSearch
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Global search value. To be applied to all columns which have searchable as true.
        /// </summary>
        public string Value { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// true if the global filter should be treated as a regular expression for advanced searching, false otherwise.
        /// Note that normally server-side processing scripts will not perform regular expression searching for performance reasons on large data sets, but it is technically possible and at the discretion of your script.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Regex { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
    <div class="contentpanel">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table mb30 table-class-ajax" data-list="post/ajaxpost">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col style="width: 4%;" />
                        <col style="width: auto;" />
                        <col style="width: 13%;" />
                        <col style="width: 9%;" />
                        <col style="width: 8%;" />
                        <col style="width: 8%;" />
                        <col style="width: 105px;" />
                    </colgroup>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Publish Date</th>
                            <th>Pageviews</th>
                            <th>Featured</th>
                            <th>Published</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- contentpanel -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable = $(".table-class-ajax").DataTable({
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "type": "POST",
                "url": "post/ajaxpost",
                "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'data': function (data) { return data = JSON.stringify(data); }
            },
            "processing": true,
            "paging": true,
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "deferRender": true,
            "columns": [
               { "data": "id" },
               { "data": "title" },
               { "data": "date" },
               { "data": "views" },
               { "data": "featured" },
               { "data": "published" },
               { "data": "action" }
            ],
            "order": [0, "asc"],
            "info": true,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You got paging turned on in your client side script for your DataTable.

```
//...
"paging": false
//...
```

Comment: my problem is its shows only the first 10 records in my database LITERALLY!

Comment: From your database? Then may be set Length to -1 in your action for an instance of DTParameters. Run SQL Server profiler to see SQL statement being generated.

Comment: What query does it generate? Is there SELECT TOP clause, didn't DTParameters.Length being set to -1 effected that query?

Answer (score 0):

In Your code if you see Datatable view model the lenth parameter states the total coloumns to be loaded for the data table.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Number of records that the table can display in the current draw.
    /// It is expected that the number of records returned will be equal to    this number, unless the server has fewer records to return.
    /// Note that this can b**e -1 to** indicate that all records should be returned (although that negates any benefits of server-side processing!)
    /// </summary>
    public int **Length** { get; set; }
```

Set the value to -1 as said in the code